# Got TransportException：Connection has been closed when using structured streaming read and write data to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using structured streaming to read and save data to cassandra. Spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.10 driver was used. The app runs fine at the start, but every 20 hours perhaps, it suspended with exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Exception during execution of SELECT "is_delete", "region_code", "gateway_id", "purpose_code", "address_code" FROM "hk_ods"."frm_firealarm_gateway" WHERE token("gateway_id") > ? AND token("gateway_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: [node1-fzy/192.168.1.191:9042] Connection has been closed
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:350)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:367)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:367)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [node1-fzy/192.168.1.191:9042] Connection has been closed
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException.copy(TransportException.java:38)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException.copy(TransportException.java:24)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:40)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultScanner.scan(Scanner.scala:34)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:342)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [node1-fzy/192.168.1.191:9042] Connection has been closed
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$ConnectionCloseFuture.force(Connection.java:1210)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$ConnectionCloseFuture.force(Connection.java:1195)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.defunct(Connection.java:445)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.exceptionCaught(Connection.java:1128)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.notifyHandlerException(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:844)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    ... 1 more
```

It shows one onde has closed the connection, but every node runs without shutdown.
And if restarted, it will run another probable 18 to 20 hours then the same exception occurs.
Can anyone helps ? Thanks very much!

Comment: What is the Spark version? Try to read data with consistency level LOCAL_QUORUM, or at least with TWO - it may help to decrease the load onto the servers. Also, this kind of the queries isn't very good for use in the Structured streaming

Comment: Spark2.2 was used.  With the default read consistency level LOCAL_QUORUM sometimes it got exception of "local read exception", so I changed the level to ONE.

Comment: Our app contains lots of demession to complete while the original data from kafka just includes some key data. If don't use Structured streaming to join static table with stream, I suppose we should cache the dimensiondata? If so we have to cache all the dimension data in ahead, but the demands always change along time, so I cant come out with a better way to fufill this goal.

Comment: The best choice for your would be upgrade to Spark 2.4 (at least), so you can use Spark Cassandra Connector 2.5 that contains so-called "direct join" that allow to pull only specific items from Cassandra when doing the join. see https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all & https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/spark-effective-joins-with-cassandra.html

Comment: Thank you! I‘ll check the new version and documents to see how to improve it.